# Runtime Error AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL in leetcode

Tags: c++, recursion, runtime-error, dynamic-programming, address-sanitizer

```
I am getting the following Runtime error:

AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==32==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x7ffcdc3e2ff8 (pc 0x00000038409c bp 0x7ffcdc3e3020 sp 0x7ffcdc3e3000 T0)
==32==ABORTING
```

while solving https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-paths-iii/ 
 
I am unable to figure out the root cause of it. 
My source code is as follows:

```
#define vvi vector<vector<int> >
#define vi vector<int>

class Solution {
public:
    int helper(vvi &grid, vvi &dp, int m, int n, int i, int j) {
        if(i < 0 || i >= n || j < 0 || j >= m || -1 == grid[i][j])
           return 0;

        if(0 == dp[i][j]) {
            if(2 == grid[i][j])
                dp[i][j] = 1;
            else
                dp[i][j] = helper(grid, dp, m, n, i - 1, j) +
                           helper(grid, dp, m, n, i, j + 1) +
                           helper(grid, dp, m, n, i + 1, j) +
                           helper(grid, dp, m, n, i, j - 1);
        }

        return dp[i][j];
    }

    int uniquePathsIII(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
        if(grid.size() == 0)
            return 0;

        int n = grid.size();
        int m = grid[0].size();
        vvi dp(n, vi(m, 0));

        return helper(grid, dp, m, n, 0, 0);
    }
};
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Each time you call `helper()` the OS must store the current call to the same function, so it can continue with the previous call. The "store" is called the **stack**. This recursion eats a lot of stack space, which is much much less than available memory for the program vars.

Comment: This question can be greatly improved by providing a small program that can be used to reproduce the error. Add the missing headers and write a `main` that feeds in a data set that triggers the Stack overflow that people can compile, run, and experiment with. Use [mre] as inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

The issue has been resolved. It was happening because the visited nodes were being pushed onto the stack again for computation and this was resulting in infinite recursion.

It was solved using a visited array that ensures that a specific block in the path is checked only once.

If you are facing similar problems then check if your recursion will terminate or loop endlessly.